# Cleaning data using macro

Tags: excel, vba

If possible, I need help with creating excel macro which will clean some fields in my spreadsheets.

I am receiving excel spreadsheets with different amount of records. And in the following spreadsheets I need to format fields like **First Name** / **Last Name** / **Job Title** / **City** (I used excel Proper() function when I did it manually). Most important, I need also to replace **Industry** field with the standard values from another sheet. And: to replace **State** (from short values, like TX to Texas), also replace **Country** from us or usa or united states of america to "United States".  (when I performed this manually, I used VlookUp () function).

Example:
I have spreadsheet(s), like:

Sheet 1, Data:

`FName    LName  Email      Title   City    ST   Phone  Industry   Country 
 John     sm     j@hotmail.com it   dallas  TX   5556663344 mobile     us
 jess     lee    jess@aol.com  ba   ny      ny   6667775656 art        usa
 nick     Jahn   nick@aol.com  ba   raleigh ny   444-3338888 tech       us`

Sheet2, State:

`ST   ST_Full
   TX   Texas
   NY   New York
   NC   North Carolina`

etc. -> all US / Canada states list

Sheet 3, Industry:

`Industry    Industry_Correct
 Mobile      Telecom
 Art         Other
 Tech        Technology`

etc. -> the list of all possible variations correct/incorrect industries

Sheet 4, Country:

`Country

  Angola
  Canada
  Russian Federation
  United States`

for the Sheet 4, I have alphabetical list of over 200 countries, and need to replace countries like "us" "Russia" to proper name from the list.

Result Sheet, (what expecting to have):

`FName LName  Title   City    ST       Phone         Industry  Country 
     John Sm      It   Dallas   Texas       555-666-3344  Telecom  United States
     Jess Lee     Ba   New York New York   666-777-5656   Other    United States
     Nick Jahn    Ba   Raleigh  New York   444-333-8888   Technology  United

                                                                          States`

`email
j@hotmail.com
jess@aol.com
nick@aol.com`

I was trying to record very simple macro; but I have very different spreadsheets - w. different amount of records - from 5 to 2000 or 3000 records.
Simple recorded macro only somehow cleaned FIXED amount of records.

Comment: It may help if you share the macro you recorded that cleans the fixed amount of records.

Comment: I think the simplest solution would be to use an INDEX MATCH or a VLOOKUP

Comment: To Praguian: I recorded many steps, to clean all field using excel functions. So, not sure if I can post this macro here...    Also, just to clarify -  I will have various (undefined) number of records in the input sheet only - in Sheet 1!     Here is that macro:

Comment: Unfortunately it's too long to share...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have your recorded macro working properly except that it is working on a fixed amount of records. You need to make the range dynamic so your macro can see how many rows of data there are automatically. Without seeing your code, its hard to tell you how to implement this. Generally, something like this will do the trick:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("[sheet name]")
'Can also reference the sheet code, which is better in my opinion. Set sht = Sheet1 or whatever number your sheet is. 

'This will fetch the last row for you
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

You may find this website helpful: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

To respond to your comments: 
You should implement this at the very beginning of your code. So what we are doing is 1) setting the sheet for the macro, 2) determining the last row of data in that sheet, and 3) you need to then use that last row to set a Range for the macro to work on, or at least go through your macro and replace row 1000 with LastRow. So, in addition to the code I provided, you may also have something like:

```
Dim myRange as Range: Set myRange = sht.Range("A2:Z" & LastRow)
```

Then you can simply reference myRange when you need your macro to do something in that range. Hope that helps. Instead of make a new post, you should be able to edit your original post to add some of your code if necessary. 
As to your IFERROR question, its hard to say the most correct approach without more information. Generally speaking, I think its better to use if/else statements, but you can certainly just use WorksheetFunction.iferror(...) if you need to replicate the same iferror functionality that is built into Excel.

Comment: To Jake:  Thank you!                                                                                My question:  Where in my macro should I implement what you've advised?                                                                                                        I can post new topic w. the code too...

Comment: Also, for now, I recorded my macro for 1 000 records (since I know we'll never have more than 1K records) and used IFERROR function where I added what I'd like to display if there error.   But, I think, it's not proper enough to do this way...